# Is it possible to define names of model's fields dynamically?

Tags: django, django-models

Now I have this code:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    xxxx_count = ForeignCountField(filter={'foreign_table__xxxx': True})
    yyyy_count = ForeignCountField(filter={'foreign_table__yyyy': True})
    zzzz_count = ForeignCountField(filter={'foreign_table__zzzz': True})
    qqqq_count = ForeignCountField(filter={'foreign_table__qqqq': True})
    ssss_count = ForeignCountField(filter={'foreign_table__ssss': True})
    rrrr_count = ForeignCountField(filter={'foreign_table__rrrr': True})
```

I want something like this:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    for code in ['xxxx','yyyy','zzzz','qqqq','ssss','rrrr']:
        setattr(self, '%s_count' % code, ForeignCountField(filter={'foreign_table__%s' % code: True}))
```

But when I try to do this, error raised: "self doesn't defined". Do I need to put this code into some other place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add fields outside model definition you have to use `add_to_class` model method:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    pass

for code in ['xxxx','yyyy','zzzz','qqqq','ssss','rrrr']:
    Mymodel.add_to_class('%s_count' % code, ForeignCountField(filter={'foreign_table__%s' % code: True})))
```

Comment: Very good point, I forgot this approach (it's been so long since I've needed it, ever since Django got abstract model inheritance).  This is probably a better solution than writing a metaclass.

Comment: Yeah, this's good working. Only one bad thing, that field's definition located in 2 different places in code: inside and outside class.

Answer (score 1):

The way to automate the creation of multiple class attributes is by writing a metaclass.  It'd certainly be possible to subclass Django's ModelBase metaclass and add the functionality you need; but it would also be overkill and probably less maintainable than just writing them out.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to know a bit more about the design decisions that got you to this point. What is a ForeignCountField and why do you need it? Shouldn't it be a property of the respective tables? (a method on the manager or a classmethod?)

Comment: Excellent question.  I almost asked this too, but figured that someone who went to the trouble of writing a ForeignCountField probably knows what they're doing and needs the denormalization.

Comment: I have 6 denormalization fields, that builded by the same principle and I want to have a more scalable method to support them. I feel 7th same field can appear every moment

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to put you're code in the constructor method **init** of your class.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    .....
    super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Edit: Sorry **this don't work**. Maybe you can try looking at [This](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels), *'this works with django 0.96. There are some modification that make it hard to adjust it with django version 1.0'.*

if you wan't it Dirty and Quick you can try something like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    letters = ["A", "B", "C"]
    for l in letters:
        exec "%s_count = models.CharField(max_length=255)" % l
```

Comment: what the difference between defining inside __init__() or outside __init__(). Only definiteness of self variable?

Comment: Yes, in __init__ self exist, outside not.

Comment: I try to do that, but my schema evolution app: "deseb" suggests to me drops all this fields. In shell, print says they are <utils.composition.ForeignCount object at ....>, but before it they were PositiveInteger. I think it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Ooh, just saw your edit. Thanks for dirty method, but I will try to find more convenient. I saw DynamicModels before, and at that time I think, that defining this fields without loop is better then doing so many changes with model.